# Closing Macro with current date

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a macro to close several files and one of them uses a current date in the file name. I need the macro to click in the workbook and then close it and save it. I think I almost have it but I just can'tget the macro to click in the active workbook, which filename will change daily. This is what I have.

```
Dim ClosePath As String
Dim ClosePathDate As String

ClosePath = "File_":
ClosePathDate = ClosePath & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"

Windows("ClosePathDate").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

I am not sure how to use " Windows("ClosePathDate") " I also tried Windows=ClosePathDate.Activate, no luck.

Please help.

Comment: Do your other windows close ok?

Comment: Windows(ClosePathDate).Activate  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work even if the workbook is open in another Excel Instance. BTW, you do not need to select it in order to close it.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ClosePath As String
    Dim ClosePathDate As String
    Dim xlObj As Object

    ClosePath = "File_":
    ClosePathDate = ClosePath & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"

    '~~> Replace "C:\" with the relevant path
    Set xlObj = GetObject("C:\" & ClosePathDate)
    xlObj.Application.Workbooks(ClosePathDate).Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Another way

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ClosePath As String
    Dim ClosePathDate As String

    ClosePath = "File_":
    ClosePathDate = ClosePath & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsx"

    Set wb = Workbooks(ClosePathDate)

    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes. `Application.Quit`. This will close Excel and will prompt you if you want to save any unsaved work. If you want to quit without those alerts then you can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before issuing the .`Quit` command.

Comment: works great, one more, is there a way to close the excel instance that is running the macro all together. Application.Quit just leaves a blank excel open for me.